# Unable to stop Derby database

Tags: glassfish-3, derby

I have Glassfish 3.1.2 installed in my local machine. I tried starting the asadmin database using the command

asadmin start-database

It started fine. Now, when I am trying to stop it, it gives me this error and won't stop.

Connection obtained for host: 0.0.0.0, port number 1527.
DRDA_NeedLocalHost.S:host: 10.0.1.6 is not local to the server running on 0.0.0.0, so cannot be used for NetworkServerControl commands
Unable to stop database.  Please check log in derby.log.
Command stop-database failed.

When I checked derby.log, this is what it shows :

host: 10.0.1.6 is not local to the server running on 0.0.0.0, so cannot be used for NetworkServerControl commands

I am not sure what to do exactly to make it stop successfully.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What is `10.0.1.6`? Your machine's IP?

Comment: Yes, that's my machine's IP

Comment: What version of derby are you using? This seems like a bug in some versions of Derby. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=host+is+not+local+to+the+server+running+on+so+cannot+be+used+for+NetworkServerControl+commands